# Kubernetes Raw API resource type

Tags: go, kubernetes

What RBAC role resource type would I use for raw type?

ex. `kubectl get --raw "/api/v1/nodes/(your-node-name)/proxy/stats/summary"`

```yaml
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: k8s-ephemeral-storage-metrics-debug
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["*"]
    verbs: ["*"]
```

or go raw API k8s calls?

```golang
content, err := clientset.RESTClient().Get().AbsPath(fmt.Sprintf("/api/v1/nodes/%s/proxy/stats/summary", currentNode)).DoRaw(context.Background())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [API documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.25/#node-v1-core) names this operation "Get Connect Proxy Path" and more specifically describes the URL as

```
GET /api/v1/nodes/{name}/proxy/{path}
```

The `.../proxy/...` part is the interesting part.  It indicates that you're not using basic CRUD operations on a Node object, but rather accessing some *subresource* of the Node.  The RBAC setup has [specific syntax for subresources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#referring-to-resources).

You need to break the URL down into its component parts
You can break this down into several component parts:

```
  (no API group)
        v
GET /api/v1/nodes/{name}/proxy/{path}
            ^^^^^        ^^^^^
           resource   subresource
```

You then use the `resource/subresource` name in the RBAC definition

```yaml
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: k8s-ephemeral-storage-metrics-debug
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["node/proxy"]
    verbs: ["get"]
```

Comment: That you for sharing that detailed answer David, one minor correction is it ended up being `resources: ["nodes/proxy"]` . After that it worked as expected.